# Accessing Properties/Methods in Facebook PHP Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook's graph API in PHP to access a user's feed.

Specifically, I want to record the names of people who posted and people who were tagged in the post.

I have been able to retrieve the name of people who posted by using the methods:

```
getProperty('from')->getProperty('name')
```

But, for whatever reason, I have not been successful in getting who the was tagged (despite similarly using `getProperty('to')` ).

As well, I have been able to accomplish this in javascript (so I believe I am correctly interpreting the structure of the data), but not PHP.

If anyone can help me retrieve the name of who is tagged in the feed by accessing the property with the getProperty methods that I have been using or by accessing the name property another way, that would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my best attempt at coding this section:

```
/* make the API call to get home*/
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/me/home'
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

//array of the 25 most recent posts
$dataPostArray = $graphObject->getPropertyAsArray('data');

$i = 0;
while($dataPostArray[$i])
{ 
    //print_r($r->getProperty('name'));
    if($dataPostArray[$i]->getProperty('from') )
    {
        echo $dataPostArray[$i]->getProperty('from')->getProperty('name');//works as intended
    }
    if($dataPostArray[$i]->getProperty('to') ) 
    {
        $temp = $dataPostArray[$i]->getProperty('to');
        $dataToArray = $temp->getPropertyAsArray('data');
        echo $dataToArray[0]->getProperty('name');
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue may be that the getPropertyAsArray method is not an option for when you are getting the data property. As an alternative to the getProperty methods. You could do it like such:

```
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

$i = 0;
while($graphObject['data'][$i])
   { 

   if($graphObject['data'][$i]->from )
   {
       //echo $graphObject['data'][$i]->from->name;//will work just as you have above

    }
   $j = 0;

   if($graphObject['data'][$i]->to->data[$j]->name ) 
   { 
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject['data'][$i]->to->data[$j]->name, 1 ) . '</pre>';

    }
    $i++;
    }
}
```